# Why is there a definite article before “rain”?

Tags: definite-article, uncountable-nouns

> Villagers are now waiting for **the** rain to come so that the rice will grow.

Why is it *the rain* in this sentence, not *rain* without the definite article? We are talking about *rain* in general to come, not any specific rain, then why are we using the definite article here?

Answer (score 1):

> We are talking about rain in general to come, not any specific rain, then why are we using the definite article here?

On the contrary, this sentence *is* talking about some specific rain, not rain in general. The specific rain is probably a *seasonal* rain which is expected to come at a predictable time, or a specific weather system such as a low pressure circulation which has been forecast to arrive and to produce rain.

The sentence is also possible without an article. Then the sense of a specific expected rain is lost.

Comment: Could you tell why we use the definite article before this: "there is a time when the rain comes", why can't we simply say "rain comes"?

Comment: You can use it with or without the article. The answer explains why and when "the" is added. It is exactly the use of the article that conveys the sense of specific expected weather.

Answer (score 1):

The speaker is identifying *which* rain the villagers are waiting for. **The** rain that arrives at a more or less specific period of time.

If **the** rain doesn't fall at the expected time, the crop will inevitably suffer.